# Python - Como intercalar adição de valores entre linha e coluna em ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

Olá, estou com a seguinte dificuldade, isso porque estou trabalhando com numpy agora, sou inexperiente...

Pois bem o meu problema é o seguinte, tenho uma tupla (w, t), sendo que o **t** se repete, de forma que quero adicionar o **t** como linhas, mas especificamente na primeira linha do array, aí depois quero verificar quais as tuplas tem o **t** igual e adicionar o w a coluna que ela pertence, ficaria assim:

```
[    t1   ,       t2     ...
  (w1, t1) ,   (w2, t2), ...
   .
   .
   .
]
```

de forma que o t sempre serão adicionados na primeira linha no eixo x, e os w nas colunas, no eixo y.

então, como poderia fazer isso?

Já vi a questão **shape**, mas não conseguir entender muito bem.
Tentei o **np.append(array, value, axis)**, mudando o valor de **axis** de 0 para 1, mas não funcionou.

Exemplo de entrada:

```
[('São', 'V'), ('Paulo', 'NPROP'), ('18', 'N'), ('de', 'PREP'), ('julho', 'N'), ('de', 'PREP'), ('1988', 'N'), ('Edu', 'NPROP')]...
```

uma lista com tuplas... no caso eu queria remover a duplicidade do valor da tupla a direita colocando-o como coluna, e o valores da esquerda estaria dentro de uma lista em sua respectiva coluna.

Saída:

```
[  'V'     , 'NPROP',           'N',         'PREP'
 ['São'], ['Paulo', 'Edu'], ['18', '1988'], ['de', 'de']
]
```

Comment: Você poderia incluir um exemplo de entrada e a respectiva saída esperada ?

Comment: @Lacobus modifquei a pergunta... me diga se deu de enteder!

Comment: E como ficaria a saída ?

Comment: @Lacobus Pronto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver o seu problema, um `dicionário` de `listas` seria mais adequado do que uma `NumPy` *array*, veja só:

```
lista = [('Sao', 'V'), ('Paulo', 'NPROP'), ('18', 'N'), ('de', 'PREP'), ('julho', 'N'), ('de', 'PREP'), ('1988', 'N'), ('Edu', 'NPROP')]

dic = {}

for a, b in lista:
    if b not in dic:
        dic[b] = [a]
    else:
        dic[b].append(a)

print(dic)
```

Saída:

```
{'N': ['18', 'julho', '1988'], 'NPROP': ['Paulo', 'Edu'], 'PREP': ['de', 'de'], 'V': ['Sao']}
```

Comment: como implementou o método **has_key()** ?

Comment: Fiz a substituição do condicional `if has_key(b)` para `if b not in dic`, que tem o mesmo comportamento e se torna mais legível.

Comment: Entendi... vou testar aqui.. muito obrigado pela ajuda....